# <a asp-controller> with asp-fragment don't work and causes exception in console

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got restaurant menu site and I want to navigate directly to a menu fragment from a landing page. This works fine when i paste the url into browser but causes exception in console after I click the link:

```
    SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /Menu#Drinks
    jquery.js (1580,2)
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
    <a asp-controller="Menu" asp-fragment="Drinks">Drinks</a>
    <a href="/Menu#Drinks">Drinks 2</a>
    <a href="http://localhost:64749/Menu#Drinks">Drinks 3</a>
```

Also this is my "Menu" controller:

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{        
    private readonly MenuService _menuSrvc;

    public MenuController(MenuService menuSrvc)
    {
        _menuSrvc = menuSrvc;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData.Model = new MenuViewModel()
        {
            MenuCategories = _menuSrvc.GetMenu(),
        };

        return View("~/Views/Menu/Menu.cshtml");
    }
}
```

All nugets are up to date. Bower.json:
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.16.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "^3.2.6"

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not fully a solution but I managed to get it to work. I'm not linking to fragment, but to another action in the controller which is redirecting to given url.

```
<a asp-controller="Menu" asp-action="RedirectToFragment" asp-route-fragment="Pizza">
        ...view more
</a>

public IActionResult RedirectToFragment(string fragment)
{
    return Redirect(string.Concat(@"\Menu#", fragment));
}
```

Leaving it here... Maybe someone will find proper solution for this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kkopieczek as this was a very annoying problem for me also.  I did have a little problem with the Redirect statement but this worked fine as another alternative:

```
  return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }) + "#" + fragment);
```